# OpenGL ES 2.0 mat4 [0][0] read

Tags: matrix, opengl-es-2.0, shader, variable-assignment

I'm trying to read a value from a uniform mat4 I've passed into a shader from within it in the following manner...

```
uniform mat4 uEffect;
...
float effect = uEffect[0][0];
```

Is this possible? The shader aint crashing, I've passed another mat4 in that works but I'm not trying to access it in this manner.  I'm later testing this value...

```
if(effect>0) blah blah blah
```

Nothing seems to make this fire even though I'm sure I'm passing in data that's greater than 0 i.e. passed in a matrix populated with just 1's confirmed via debugging mode.

Thanks in advance for any help and advise...

Mark

Comment: I believe this should be doable. But comparing float against int _effect > 0_ doesn't necessarily compile too well.

Comment: This code is inside the shader which is more like C hence not 0.0f...

Comment: Well, _0.0f_ should cause a compile error too. _0.0_ is more of what you ought to use. OpenGL ES 2.0 GLSL specification says there is no implicit conversions, hence you shouldn't be able to compare _float > 0_ ; http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf (4. Variables and Types , the last sentence of introduction) . But if you see no compile error, maybe your GLSL compiler isn't too strict on following the specification.

Comment: I made a mistake in my code using...

uEffectsHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "uEffects");

...instead of ....

uEffectsHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uEffects");

...and now the following works inside the shader...

float effect = uEffects[1][1];,

Thanks for you comments.